# src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'InputData'. It was detected that 'InputData' is in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'

Tags: namespaces, xsd, wsdl, bpel, complextype

I'm trying to make the input for my BPEL a complextype, but I get the error in object.
I hope someone is able to give me a hint. Thank you in advance.
This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<definitions name="testBPEL2"
        targetNamespace="http://test.bpel2"
        xmlns:tns="http://test.bpel2"
        xmlns:plnk="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/plnktype"
        xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
        >

<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     TYPE DEFINITION - List of types participating in this BPEL process 
     The BPEL Designer will generate default request and response types
     but you can define or import any XML Schema type and use them as part 
     of the message types.
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->    
    <types>
        <schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
                targetNamespace="http://test.bpel2" 
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

            <element name="testBPEL2Request">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="input" type="InputData"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>

            <element name="testBPEL2Response">
                <complexType>
                    <sequence>
                        <element name="result" type="OutPutData"/>
                    </sequence>
                </complexType>
            </element>

            <complexType name="InputData">
                <sequence>
                    <element name="citta" type="string"></element>
                    <element name="id_libro" type="int"></element>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>

            <complexType name="OutputData">
                <sequence>
                    <element name="libreria" type="string"></element>
                    <element name="prezzo" type="int"></element>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
        </schema>
    </types>
```

I hope someone is able to give me a hint. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess

```
<sequence>
  <element name="input" type="InputData"/>
</sequence>
```

should read

```
<sequence>
  <element name="input" type="tns:InputData"/>
</sequence>
```